# Test question: The {people | peoples} of Europe are white-skinned

Tags: word-choice, plural-forms, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

This question is from a test:

> The {people | peoples} of Europe are white-skinned.

Which is correct? Can we use either?

Comment: Have you looked in a [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/people) before you asked the question? Whichever meaning of people you want, your sentence is not only unclear but ill chosen. Probably a [duplicate](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/69250/2818) anyway.

Comment: As @Jim pointed out, we need more context to answer this properly. Please refer to [meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more information on this. Thanks!

Comment: ....And if you _have_ looked in a dictionary, what did you see?  Explain why you are confused about this distinction.  That will make it much easier for people to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Both answers could be correct. It depends on whether we think of Europeans as one group or as several.

Since Europe comprises a number of groups with distinct cultures, languages, etc., the best answer is probably *peoples* according to the following definition.

> 3. pl.
>      peo·ples
>      A body of persons sharing a common religion, culture, or language: *the peoples of central Asia.*

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Peoples&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

Thus: *[All] the [different] peoples of Europe are white-skinned.*

Comment: Thanks, Jim Reynolds. Do you mean the use of "people" in the sentence is incorrect?

Comment: I'd like to know whether  "people of Europe are white-skinned" is meaningful or not.

Comment: I really apologize to you, Jim. The sentence is from a test. The question is:the …………… of Europe are white-skinned. (A) people (B) peoples

Answer (score 0):

One would say

> the **peoples** of Europe

to mean the **different groupings** of people in Europe: nationality, height, weight, skin colour, etc.

The **European people** are **the group** of people in Europe

> We the **people** of the United States

refers to Americans as one group.

You could say

> the ***white skinned*** **people** of Europe

since they are **one category**.

> The **people** of Europe are white skinned

refers to the **entire group of Europeans**, so this statement is **false** since there are many colours of skin within the Europe community

A more correct statement would be

> Some of the **peoples** of Europe are white skinned
>   *of the* ***various groups*** *of people in Europe*
>
> Some of the **people** of Europe are white skinned
>   *out of* ***all*** *the people in Europe*

Both are correct, it just depends what you want to say

> There are many white skinned **people** amoungst the **peoples** of Europe

The question as posed from your test is a **bad question**
I'm guessing they will have **people** as the correct answer since **peoples** would imply **differences**

Answer (score -3):

Yes. The word "people" itself represent all people of Europe so no need to putting s in it.

Comment: pl peoples [count] : a group of people who make up a race, tribe, nation, etc.
A people who migrated across the Bering Strait.
The native peoples of Mexico
Peoples of Asia.